# How to expose kafka brokers ports externally in Kubernetes on AWS private/public VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, networking, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I cannot access Kafka brokers externally (from a public IP address).

I am using https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka

It has a very good guide, but I believe their built in method of  exposing ports publicly does not work since I am running this cluster privately in a private/public VPC on AWS.

I believe their built in method of outside access simply exposes host ports on private subnet address (Is this correct?)

I know I can set up a load balancer per broker and alias a domain to each load balancer. But then I'm incurring extra costs on load balancers.

I have been looking at ingress resources, have successfully setup an nginx controller that would communicate to different services based on the url path to the host domain.

However with nginx I would receive a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable with a curl to the url (would get success on echoserver url). So I quickly realised that http requests aren't making sense here. Not to the brokers anyway?

I'm now stuck on learning nginx and a succesful way of proxying the requests.

Is there a specific proxy protocol I should use?

This could also be incorrect server.properties config.

When using nginx I would have the ingress resource connect to the outside-${BROKER_ID} services (I changed the first one to a clusterIP service, others stayed as NodePort). To me this is external DNS mapping to internal IPs. So I would think that the default listeners setting on the Kafka server.properties are OK for this?. Otherwise should the listener become the domain aliased to the load balancer? I had tried the domain with the URL path as an advertised listener, but that didn't make any sense to me, and resulted in crash loops!

For anyone wanting to look at configs, I'm currently running with the default (kinda, 5 pzoos, no ezoos [they were always stuck as pending]) version of:

```
https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka
```

This can be setup very quickly on an existing cluster (For AWS):

```
git clone https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka
cd kubernetes-kafka
(AWS) rm configure/!(aws*)
kubectl apply -f configure
kubectl apply -f 00-namespace*
kubectl apply -f rbac*
kubectl apply -f zookeeper
kubectl apply -f kafka
kubectl config set-context $(kubectl config current-context) --namespace=kafka
```

I am running this version of nginx

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/aws/service-l4.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/aws/patch-configmap-l4.yaml
```

The echoserver came from:

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/master/addons/ingress-nginx
```

Specifc lines used:

```
kubectl run echoheaders --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4 --replicas=1 --port=8080
kubectl expose deployment echoheaders --port=80 --target-port=8080 --name=echoheaders-x
kubectl expose deployment echoheaders --port=80 --target-port=8080 --name=echoheaders-y
```

Here is my ingress resource for nginx:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echomap
  # annotations:
  # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: brokers.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /broker0
        backend:
          serviceName: outside-0
          servicePort: 31100
      - path: /broker1
        backend:
          serviceName: outside-1
          servicePort: 31101
      - path: /broker2
        backend:
          serviceName: outside-2
          servicePort: 31102
      - path: /bar
        backend:
          serviceName: echoheaders-y
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /foo
        backend:
          serviceName: echoheaders-x
          servicePort: 80
```

EDIT:
I focused on getting external access through load balancers, and somewhat succeeded. Problems can be found here https://serverfault.com/questions/949367/can-connect-to-kafka-but-cannot-consume

Pretty sure nginx isn't going to work as ingress? I can't figure out how a http request becomes a TCP request.

Moving on to internal kafka streams apps now. Will come back to this when having a separate cluster for kafka streams becomes more necessary.

Comment: Are you sure the listeners are configured for Kafka correctly? https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: That was a good read thank you. Actually have the problem of bad internal listener when setup with load balances and domain alias. This helped solved that.

Comment: @cricket_007. If I connect externally, the metdata returned contains external hostnames. However if I attempt to consume from a topic. I will receive Host Resolution Failure on the correct external address. I receive 3 errors because I have 3 brokers. 

Host resolution failure: broker0.my-domain:{BROKER_PORT}/0:

Is the 0 at the end the broker ID? the other errors end with 1 or 2 and would be the correct ids according to the host name. Internal connections are fine.

Comment: I believe that is the ID, yes, but I didn't think the ID could be less than 1. I don't really have k8s-kafka experience myself to give good guidance on that. I do know the Confluent Helm Charts specific NodePorts for the services

Comment: @cricket_007 coming back to this quite late, I'm wondering if you ever read the update on how load balancers worked? There was still some strange issues, namely kafkacat resolving hostnames perfectly fine with the -L option, but when set to consume or produce, "No such host is know"

Comment: `-L` reads the metadata in the controller, which is a different protocol than what the clients use to do the bootstrapping of the brokers. These indirectly get the advertised listeners from Zookeeper